# Nullable database property but texbox still shows red border when content deleted

Tags: wpf, validation, entity-framework-4, binding

Hi I am binding a WPF textbox to an Entity Framework property as follows:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,2" 
         Text="{Binding Path=MyEntityObject.SizeLower, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

It binds fine to the property and when I change it, it saves to the DB as expected. But if I delete the content of the Textbox I get the red error border around it. I dont have any validator in place so I am guessing the texbox is complaining about the value not being nullable. But in fact this property in the DB is nullable, so I cannot understand why it would error.

The system generated EF property definition is as follows:

```
<EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty:=false, IsNullable:=true)>
<DataMemberAttribute()>
Public Property SizeLower() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int64)
    Get
        Return _SizeLower
    End Get
    Set
        OnSizeLowerChanging(value)
        ReportPropertyChanging("SizeLower")
        _SizeLower = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value)
        ReportPropertyChanged("SizeLower")
        OnSizeLowerChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Private _SizeLower As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int64)
```

Is there something I am missing? I thought the binding system was able to determine if a property was nullable and allow nulls if so?

How can I see what the error is? Hovering doesnt seem to do the trick.

Thanks for any advice.

===================================
ADDITIONAL INFO

If I select all and delete, then change focus, the validation box appears. Here's a screencapture before and after. Also I have confirmed that I can manually put NULLs in the database for the bound properties so thats not the problem.

DENIED. Tried to put picture here but I dont have 10 points...!
Here is an offsite link instead: [CLICK HERE](http://ebaypics.net/ProgrammingPics/RedSelectionBox.gif)

Comment: TripleAntigen.. can you please upload the screenshot when it shows red border on deleting the text? I wanna see this myself.. since it seems so strange : |... and maybe screenshots would help us to answer your question. :-)

Comment: Thanks Nawaz see revised question. The image is in an offsite link, because it would not accept an image till I have 10 points.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should add the `TargetNullValue` property to your binding:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,2" 
         Text="{Binding Path=MyEntityObject.SizeLower, 
         Mode=TwoWay, 
         TargetNullValue=''}" />
```

This tells the binding to treat null values in `MyEntityObject.SizeLower` as string.empty for display, and string.empty as null when setting.

Comment: Ahh you are a legend Philip Rieck, that did the trick!! Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: Likewise, thank you Philip for answering! Worked like a charm!