# How to set DataTable Value to null in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have grid designed in WPF that uses a DataTable as ItemsSource that i would like to be editable by the user.
If i change the displayed numeric values to other numbers it works perfectly but it doesn't allow the deletion of the value which i need to do.

**ViewModel Code:**

```
    public class DataInfo
    {
        public DataInfo()
        {
            Table = CreateDataTable();
        }

        public DataTable Table { get; set; } 

        private DataTable CreateDataTable()
        {
            var table = new DataTable("MyTable");
            DataColumn col = table.Columns.Add("MyColumn", typeof(int));
            col.AllowDBNull = true;

            for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(i);
            }

            return table;
        }
    }
```

**WPF Grid Code:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table.DefaultView}"/>
```

**The grid displaying the error:**

[image]

Comment: @Crowcoder No, I already have AllowDBNull set to true. What i need is to allow the user to delete the value in the view.

Comment: OK, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199551/how-do-you-clear-a-cell-so-it-gets-null-value-in-wpf-datagrid). I cannot vote as duplicate a second time. I tried it myself and it works.